# How to update the users table in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to update the value of one column of  the 'users' table. This is the code of the controller:

```
<?php


class RankController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
    //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {   
        // Create an array of all  users
        $users = User::all();
        // Return the view of change rank with users
        return view('rank.edit')->with('users', $users);
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $this->validate($request, [
            'rank' => 'required',
            'user_id' => 'required',
     ]);
     $id = $request->input('user_id');
     $user = User::find($id);
     $user->rank = $request->input('rank');
     $user->save();


     return redirect('../public/home')->with('succes', 'The rank id is'.$id.'         '.$user.'<br>'.'<br>'.$user->rank);

      }

    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function edit($id)
    {

    }


    public function update(Request $request, id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }


}
```

After checking the variables I find the problem: 'save()' method doesn't work, and I cant't figure out why it doesn't work. Any ideas why doesn't work?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the user_name the username or the id? Is it actually finding a user?

Comment: @aynber user_name is finding the id.  The 'find' find the user and the value of the user->rank is changed, but isn't saved in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've changed your `App\User` model to be keyed off of the `user_name`, you're searching for the user incorrectly.

```
$username = $request->input('user_name');

$user = User::where('user_name', $username)->firstOrFail();

// ...
```

`find()` searches by the primary key, which is the `id` column by default.